# perl snmpwalk to string

Tags: python, perl

Normally I work with Python but I have a project in Perl.  So: What is the process for directing the results of an snmpwalk to a string?  I would like to search the string to see if it contains a smaller string.

Here is what I have so far:

```
foreach (@list){
        chomp($_);
        system("snmpwalk -v 2c -c community-string $_   oid-hidden");
        if (index($string, $substring) != -1) {
            print "'$string' contains '$substring'\n";
        }

}
```

Comment: I would recommend using a module, either [Net::SNMP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SNMP), a pure-Perl module, or [SNMP.pm](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/perl-SNMP-README.html), the Perl bindings to the net-snmp library.

Answer (score 2):

`system` function doesn't return the function output, use `qx//` or backticks, so your snmpwalk call line will look like this:

`my $output = qx/snmpwalk -v 2c -c community-string $_   oid-hidden/;`

And then you do with the output variable what you need, for more info I'd refer you to http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators

However in more general terms I'd follow the advice in @ThisSuitIsBlackNot's comment...